# incrementing a set if existing

Tags: javascript, set, increment

I have a string "abacabad" being passed in to my function as `s`

**What I want to do:**

- create a new set
- go through each letter from the string. if the letter exists I increment it by 1
- if it doesn't exist we create the set by initializing it as 1

**What my code is logging:**

Set(0) { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1 }

**what it should be logging:**

Set(0) { a: 4, b: 2, c: 1, d: 1 }

---

```js
function solution(s) {
  arr = new Set()
  for (e of s) {
    if (e in arr) {
      arr[e]++;
    }
    if (arr.has(e) == false) {
      arr[e] = 1;
    }
  }
  console.log(arr)
}

solution('abacabad');
```

Comment: Please consider using [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), since leaving out them creates [implicit global variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#implicit_globals_and_outer_function_scope).

Comment: There is an issue with the second if, and also how you add values to the set. `let s = new Set(); s['a'] = 1; s.has('a') // false` You shouldn't use Set as key/value storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Set` is a collection of unique elements. It's not a `Map` (key/value) store.

There's tons of issues in that code so I won't enumerate them all, but you simply aren't using the right kind of object and then are mixing APIs, notably defining keys of objects mixed with the actual `Set`'s API.

```js
function solution(s) {
  const countByChar = new Map();
  for (char of s) {
    const count = countByChar.get(char) || 0;
    countByChar.set(char, count + 1);
  }
  return countByChar;
}

const countByChar = solution('abacabad');

console.log(Array.from(countByChar.entries()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're conflating two different data structures:

- Sets, which are collections of *values only* (eg `('a, 'b', 'c', 'd')`, and
- Objects, which are collections of key-value pairs (eg `{ a: 1, b: 2 }`)

Set methods include `.has` and `.add`. But Sets are also objects, so you can use standard object property assignment on them as well - *but you shouldn't*. If you want a Set, use Set methods (and Set methods only) for collecting data on it. Here, you're putting a property directly onto the Set object (with `arr[e] =`), but you're using the Set method `.has`, which checks something completely different. `.add` and `has` looks at values in the Set's internal data structure (not visible by any mechanism other than other Set methods), and you're never using `.add`, so your Set never gets any values put into it.

A Set won't work well here anyway, because you want a collection of key-value pairs, not just a collection of values. Use a standard object instead, or a Map.

```js
function solution(s) {
  const obj = {};
  for (const char of s) {
    obj[char] ??= 0;
    obj[char]++;
  }
  console.log(obj);
}

solution('abacabad');
```

If you wanted a Map:

```js
function solution(s) {
  const map = new Map();
  for (const char of s) {
    map.set(
      char,
      (map.get(char) || 0) + 1
    );
  }
  console.log([...map.entries()]);
}

solution('abacabad');
```